# Numerical solution to PDE system depends on names of functions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Perhaps this is somehow related to the post:
[Numerical solution to PDE seems to contradict initial values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125301/numerical-solution-to-pde-seems-to-contradict-initial-values)

but still it may be useful.

Consider this code (I am using Mathematica 10.4):

```
sol := NDSolve[{
    D[e[x, t], x] == I u[x, t],
    D[u[x, t], t] == -u[x, t] + I e[x, t] + I s[x, t],
    D[s[x, t], t] == I u[x, t],
    s[x, 0] == 0, u[x, 0] == 0, e[0, t] == 1
    }, {e, u, s}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}] // Flatten

psol[x_, t_] = u[x, t] /. sol;
ssol[x_, t_] = s[x, t] /. sol;
esol[x_, t_] = e[x, t] /. sol;

Plot[Abs[psol[x, 0]], {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[Abs[ssol[t, 1]], {t, 0, 1}]
Plot[Abs[esol[t, 1]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

If you only rename the variables, e.g. replace u[x, t] by p[x, t], the result of the execution changes.

Comment: I think this might be caused by the same behavior that's discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17926/245). It happens in your context because the solution is probably not numerically unique and the variable ordering affects which of the possible solutions is chosen. I tried renaming the function `u` to `p` and found what you describe. But if I rename `u` to `z` (which maintains the lexicographical order of the variables), the result is *not* changed.

Comment: @Jens You suspicion is supported by the fact that the solution changes depending on whether the name comes before or after `s` alphabetically.

Comment: @Jens I see you updated your comment too.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Simplify`; this is a know issue documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) and in this (duplicate) [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125301/18437). The problem is that I do not have a reliable way to detect this and warn about it. Once I come up with something it will be implemented.